# How to use custom video resolution when use AVFoundation and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput on mac

Tags: size, avfoundation, frame, capture

I need to process each frame of captured video frame, although `AVCaptureDevice.formats` provided so many different dimension of frame sizes, it seems `AVCaptureSession` only support those frame sizes defined in presets.

I've also tried to set `AVCaptureDevice.activeFormat` before `AVCaptureInputDevice` or after, no matter what setting I set, if I set `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` in `AVCaptureSession`, it always give me a frame of 1280x720. Similar , If i set `AVCaptureSessionPreset` 640x480, then I can only get frame size of 640x480.

So, How can I set a custom video frame size like 800x600?
Using Media Foundation under windows or V4L2 under linux, it's easy to set any custom frame size when capture.

It seems not possible to do this under mac.

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there isn't a way to do this. All the code I've seen to do video capture uses the presets.

The [documentation for AVCaptureVideoDataOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_8) for the video settings property says

> The only key currently supported is the kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey key.

so the other answers of passing in video settings won't work and it will just ignore these parameters.

Comment: It works. May be undocumented. Kindly see sample at https://github.com/kiranpradeep/cameraResolution

Answer (score 2):

Set `kCVPixelBufferWidthKey` and `kCVPixelBufferHeightKey` options on `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` object. Minimal sample as below ( add error check ).

```
_sessionOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

NSDictionary *pixelBufferOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:width], (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:height], (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                              nil];
[_sessionOutput setVideoSettings:pixelBufferOptions];
```

Note: This width/height will override session preset width/height (if different).

Comment: This doesn't work. As @Bourne said, "The only key currently supported is the kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey key." If you try your code, you get an error saying, "videoSettings dictionary contains one or more unsupported (ignored) keys".

Comment: @eyuelt It works. Kindly see sample at https://github.com/kiranpradeep/cameraResolution

Comment: You're right. It does work on OSX. Sorry, I didn't realize that this question was for OSX. I was looking for a solution to this problem on iOS.

Comment: Actually the solution you quote is for still images, not video.

Comment: @AndrewSmith This is for video itself and not for still images. Kindly try running above github sample on your mac.

Answer (score 0):

Use videoSettings property of AVCapturwVideoDataOutput to describe the pixel format, width and height In a dictionary.